# Auto Prediction In A ListView

Tags: android, listview

I found this fascinating and want to explore more. A `ListView` with `Auto-Prediction` such that when I enter something in the search bar and as soon as I get close to a proper dictionary word, the `ListView` contracts with suggestions. I hope I could explain it well. What is working behind the scenes ? Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a "filter" for the list view. There are a lot of examples. 
[Here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/) is one

A search for listview filter on google will give you a ton of examples.